# How to show label after every nth tick in Vega chart

Tags: label, linechart, axes, vega-lite, vega

I am trying to plot count vs time using Vega chart. I have set tickCount to specify the number of ticks in the chart. But corresponding labels have lot of space in between (Here there is almost 8 ticks gap between two labels). Is there a way to show the label after every nth tick in the chart. For eg if my label spans 5 ticks, I should plot a label after every 7 ticks so that there is only one tick between two labels ?

[I want to show a label after every 6th tick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFTA2.png)

[Link of my spec in vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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)

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd remove `labelSeparation` and also lower the `tickCount`. Here is what it can look like with 15 as the tick count.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @dominik, removing labelSeparation lowers the gap, but the labels appear very close to each other. It looks difficult to distinguish between any two labels. Can we add some spacing between the labels ? So that any two labels would appear separate from each other.

Comment: `labelSeparation` is the space in pixels between labels.